# Do paired electrons have no higher order magnetic multipoles?

Tags: electrons, orbitals, multipole-expansion

An electron pair consists of an up and down electron in an energetically favorable condition where their magnetic dipole moments cancel each other. However, does that also mean they have no quadrupole moment? If we have a non-uniform magnetic field, would it still be energetically favorable for the up and down electrons to have the same probability density, or could the probability density of the up electron vs. down electron be shifted by different amounts?